# "Unknown" Sickness of my rooster

Tags: health, safety, diseases, medicines, chickens

My rooster presents some symptoms: weakness in legs, he has (I suppose) plantar pododermatitis that seems to be advanced because I notice swelling and cracks, he also shows drowsiness and no longer sings. What can I do for treating him? How can I improve his status? He is 2 years old.

He presents this drowsiness since some months ago when he had botulism due to rotten corn but now is more notable.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! When did the rooster last seen a veterinarian?

Comment: Thank you! Well there is no veterinarian in my district, so I always have been investigated in Internet taking in account the symptoms of my pet and then, I can heal it.

Comment: I am sorry, without a diagnosis we can not give you advice. Guessing is not welcome here, and diagnosis without physical contact to the animal will be not possible. If you have a diagnosis, then you can ask for specific advice how to treat it and we will be happy to help you. This question will be deleted, because of the rules of this site.